# BSOD - Multiple IRP Complete Requests

Tags: windows-xp, bsod

I've been getting a BSOD with the error message "MULTIPLE_IRP_COMPLETE_REQUESTS" for the past few days and I can't seem to figure out what the cause is. I've checked the event viewer, and even though its 10:10 PM on my clock, the last recorded event in the event viewer is at 7:25 PM, and it's not even an error. There doesn't seem to be any pattern, and I can't intentionally trigger the BSOD. It just happens out of nowhere. Can anyone tell me what this is and what's causing it?

EDIT: Ok, I've downloaded BlueScreenView and this is what I've got.

```
"The problem seems to be caused by the following file: USBPORT.SYS"
...
*** STOP: 0x00000044 (0x815e2bd0, 0x00000d64, 0x00000000, 0x00000000)

*** USBPORT.SYS - Address 0xf69b20d5 base at 0xf69a8000 DateStamp 0x47c58999
```

Now that I think about it, these crashes started happening not too long after I bought and started using my brand new USB wi-fi stick...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Bug Check 0x44: MULTIPLE_IRP_COMPLETE_REQUESTS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff558982(VS.85).aspx) sounds like it's probably a driver bug. Likely candidates: any USB filter drivers (e.g. for VIA chipsets), and the USB wi-fi network interface driver. Check with the manufacturers to see if there is an updated driver for these devices. Also, I seem to remember that there were some significant USB hotfixes between XP SP1 and SP2, so make sure Windows is fully up-to-date including service packs.

Failing that, try using process of elimination to narrow down the problem. Does it still crash if you...

- Unplug the USB wi-fi network interface?
- Replace it with a different brand?
- Plug it into a PCI plug-in USB host controller card instead of the motherboard?

Are you running any applications that stress the network more than most? (e.g. BitTorrent, networked games, etc.) Not that you shouldn't run them, but they tend to bring out the bugs in network drivers.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [BlueScreenView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx) to recreate the BSOD, so please analyze the problem as much as possible on your side, and add more info to your post.

> BlueScreenView scans all your minidump
>   files created during 'blue screen of
>   death' crashes, and displays the
>   information about all crashes in one
>   table. For each crash, BlueScreenView
>   displays the minidump filename, the
>   date/time of the crash, the basic
>   crash information displayed in the
>   blue screen (Bug Check Code and 4
>   parameters), and the details of the
>   driver or module that possibly caused
>   the crash (filename, product name,
>   file description, and file
>   version). For each crash
>   displayed in the upper pane, you can
>   view the details of the device drivers
>   loaded during the crash in the lower
>   pane. BlueScreenView also mark the
>   drivers that their addresses found in
>   the crash stack, so you can easily
>   locate the suspected drivers that
>   possibly caused the crash.

The usual reason for such problems is a bad driver or a buggy application integrated into the system (such as an antivirus).

BlueScreenView may with some luck help you guess at the driver in question.

Make sure that your computer is fully patched, that all drivers are as much as possible up to date (get them from the manufacturer's site rather than from Windows Update). Uninstall all antivirus and firewall for a limited time until it becomes clear whether they are to blame, then add them one by one.

If you're not sure which applications start with Windows, use [Autoruns for Windows](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx) to analyze auto-start programs.

If this is happening frequently, you might try working in Safe mode. In this mode no user applications are started, so if the problem persists then it's in Windows itself.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say why it happens unless you have some dump. Here are the steps you could use to [configure the dumps](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307973)